# Updating an entity that has a one to many relationship results in "instance of entity type cannot be tracked..."

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

The update will work **unless* I set the Professions property to the same value that it already is, and then I get

> The instance of entity type 'Profession' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'Id'} is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached

This can be a common scenario because an API call may want to change one property but send the full entity.

I have the following entity types:

**PlatformEnrollment**

```cs
public class PlatformEnrollmentEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    ...
    public virtual ICollection<PlatformEnrollmentProfessionEntity> Professions { get; set; }
}
```

**Profession**

```cs
public class ProfessionEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

**PlatformEnrollmentProfession**

```cs
public class PlatformEnrollmentProfessionEntity
{
    public int PlatformEnrollmentId { get; set; }
    [JsonIgnore]
    public PlatformEnrollmentEntity PlatformEnrollment { get; set; }
    public int ProfessionId { get; set; }
    public ProfessionEntity Profession { get; set; }
}
```

This is the method used to update

```cs
public async Task<PlatformEnrollment> Update(PlatformEnrollment platformEnrollment)
{
    var existing = await _db.PlatformEnrollments
        .Where(p => p.Id == platformEnrollment.Id)
        //.Include(p => p.Professions)
        .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
    var entry = _db.Entry(existing);
            
    entry.CurrentValues.SetValues(platformEnrollment);
    entry.Entity.Professions = _mapper.Map<List<PlatformEnrollmentProfessionEntity>>(platformEnrollment.Professions);
    try
    {
        var updated = await _db.SaveChangesAsync();

        if (updated > 0)
        {
            return _mapper.Map<PlatformEnrollment>(entry.Entity);
        }
        else
        {
            throw new DbServiceLayerException($"Failed to update PlatformEnrollment {platformEnrollment}");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _logger.LogCritical($"Attempt to update Platform Enrollment {platformEnrollment} failed: {ex.Message}, {ex.InnerException}");
        throw new DbServiceLayerException($"Attempt to update Platform Enrollment {platformEnrollment} failed: {ex.Message}");
    }
}
```

This is the test I've been working in to try and figure this out:

```cs
[Fact]
public async Task PlatformEnrollment_Update()
{
    var existing = _db.PlatformEnrollments
        .AsNoTracking()
        .SingleOrDefault(p => p.Id == defaultPlatformEnrollment.Id);
    Assert.Equal(existing.Id, defaultPlatformEnrollment.Id);
    existing.CourseSectionId = 402;
    await service.Update(mapper.Map<PlatformEnrollment>(existing));
    var updated = _db.PlatformEnrollments
      .AsNoTracking()
      .SingleOrDefault(p => p.Id == defaultPlatformEnrollment.Id);
    Assert.Equal(existing.CourseSectionId, updated.CourseSectionId);

    // Add another profession
    if (updated.Professions == null)
    {
        updated.Professions = new List<PlatformEnrollmentProfessionEntity>();
    }

    updated.Professions.Add(new PlatformEnrollmentProfessionEntity { ProfessionId = 2 });

    await service.Update(mapper.Map<PlatformEnrollment>(updated));

    var updatedReturned = await service.GetPlatformEnrollment(updated.Id);
    Assert.NotNull(updatedReturned.Professions.SingleOrDefault(p => p.ProfessionId == 2));

    // Update the profession
    updatedReturned.Professions.First().ProfessionId = 1;
    updatedReturned = await service.Update(mapper.Map<PlatformEnrollment>(updatedReturned));


    ------------- THE FAILING PART -----------------
    // Add the same profession
    updatedReturned.Professions.First().ProfessionId = 1;
    updatedReturned = await service.Update(mapper.Map<PlatformEnrollment>(updatedReturned));
    ------------- /THE FAILING PART -----------------


    // Remove the profession
    updatedReturned.Professions.Clear();
    await service.Update(mapper.Map<PlatformEnrollment>(updatedReturned));
    updatedReturned = await service.GetPlatformEnrollment(updated.Id);
    Assert.Empty(updatedReturned.Professions);
}
```

I guess I expected that it would just work like this, not sure what I'm doing wrong.  Just to be sure, I'm including a screenshot that shows I'm not trying to add a duplicate `Profession`:

[image]

**Edit**
I'm starting to wonder if it's simply how I've done my test/my lack of understanding for how EF tracks entities.  If I update my test to the following it works

```cs
updatedReturned = await service.Update(mapper.Map<PlatformEnrollment>(updatedReturned));
updatedReturned = await service.GetPlatformEnrollment(updated.Id);
//// Add the same profession
updatedReturned.Professions.First().ProfessionId = 1;
updatedReturned = await service.Update(mapper.Map<PlatformEnrollment>(updatedReturned));
```

The only difference is that, instead of using the returned entity from `service.Update`, I get another copy via the service and update that.

Comment: I'm not sure but I would say that `_mapper.Map<List<PlatformEnrollmentProfessionEntity>>(platformEnrollment.Professions)` would not match the ids of entities to update existing but rather just create new ones and fill the list with them.

Comment: What are you trying to do/solve with all these mapping calls?

Comment: In tests you should always completely separate the Arrange, Act, and Assert phases. Code in these phases should never be affected by state from other phases. Using the same `service` all the time seems to violate this principle. (As does littering the test with `Assert` statements).

Comment: @Progman the mapping in the tests are just getting the data the way I need it for what I'm going to do next.

Comment: @GertArnold Ok - I'll clean these up

Comment: @ChrisRockwell Please [edit] your question to include your source code as a working [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.